# When you "miss someone so much"

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrases

I was wondering how to say I miss you **so much** in an exaggerated way?

I know the following structures:

> **a.** I miss you **to pieces**.  
> **b.** I miss you **to the moon and back**.  (I have my doubts whether this construction can be used for "missing") 
> **c.** I miss you **to death**.

Finally, I wonder if there are some other similar structures especially in AmE.

Comment: Why would you say that people sometimes emphasise words? What has your research showed you? Also, have you got sources for "I miss you to pieces?" because that is not idiomatic at all. It's normally "I love you to pieces/bits", I have never in all my years heard it used for anything else.

Comment: Please have a look on the following links @Astralbee: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.englishforums.com/English/WhatDoesMissPiecesMean/brkzgr/amp.htm  or  https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3Fterm%3Dmiss%2520you%2520to%2520pieces%26amp%3Dtrue

Comment: Also, please have a look on the comparison below: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=miss+you+to+pieces%2Cmiss+you+to+bits%2Cmiss+you+to+death&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmiss%20you%20to%20pieces%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmiss%20you%20to%20death%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

You can use any idiom that you have posted, here are examples from books.

- *to the moon and back*:

Vivian Kolodziej (American). **I Miss You to the Moon and Back**.

---

- *to pieces*:

Jan Karon (American). **To Be Where You Are**.

> But I'll miss you to pieces.

---

- *in the worst way*:

Steve Kralick. **In the Shade of the Caribbean**.

> I miss you in the worst way. I baked your favorite birthday cake, and you never got to see it.

---

- *to death*:

Marisa Santi. **Dancing To Happiness**.

> I miss you to death, Robbie!

---

- *so bad one can taste it*

---

- *something fierce*:

Michelle Irwin. **Phoebe Reede: The Untold Story: Complete Series**.

> We would miss each other something fierce as soon as we said goodbye.